# Proper way to show 'AfterSignInMessagePage'

Tags: java, redirect, authentication, wicket

I have an application with a `MainPage` with `@AuthorizeInstantiation` and a `SignInPage`.

I want to show the user an (optional) message after signing in, but before the `MainPage`.

I thought about this, and I think I can achieve this by calling `setReponsePage(AfterSignInMessagePage.class)` in the constructor of my `MainPage`. This seems a bit messy, as the `MainPage` is being constructed, but doesn't need to.
Another option would be to do the `setReponsePage(AfterSignInMessagePage.class)` in the `SignInPage` logic, but that seems also too tightly coupled.

What would be the proper way to do a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

IMO you need logic in #onSuccessfulLogin()

```
     if (showMsg) 
        setResponsePage(AfterSignInMessagePage.class) 
     else 
        setResponsePage(MainPage.class)
```

AfterSignInMessagePage will probably show just for few seconds and then auto-redirect to MainPage.

You can also use `throw new RestartResponseException(SomePage.class)` instead of `setResponsePage(...)` if you don't want to continue with the rest of the method/constructor body.